# where is the all event implemented in backbone.js source?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm reading through the Backbone source and I'm looking at the on function -

```
on: function(name, callback, context) {
  if (!(eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) && callback)) return this;
  this._events || (this._events = {});
  var list = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
  list.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
  return this;
},
```

I don't see any special case for the 'all' event - where is this implemented?

Comment: The special case is in `trigger` not `on`. `if (allEvents) triggerEvents(allEvents, arguments);`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `on('all' ,...)` your callback is pushed into `this.events.all` array:

```
var list = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);//-> this._events.all = []
```

Then when the `trigger` is fired it checks for:

```
var allEvents = this._events.all
```

Comment: so where's the all flag set? simply posting something I've already read and tried to use to answer my own question does not help.

Comment: This answers it, which part are you still confused about, @praks5432? `_events.all` is set in `on` (this answer's first code block) and in `trigger` it calls the callback (second code block).